# Is it possible to get the element type of a List in DTE T4?

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

I have a class with a List property in it:

```
class Test
{
    public List<int> Indices { get; private set; }
}
```

Using text templates I want to create automated code. Using DTE I can find the CodeClass and iterate through all the elements to find all [CodeProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeproperty.aspx). I can write the complete type by printing:

```
WriteLine(codeProperty.Type.AsFullName);
//Prints: System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>
```

But now I'd like to know: is it possible to retrieve the type of the element in the List (in this case int, or System.Int32)?

Comment: Hi RobbinMarcus, did you find a solution to your problem? Because I have the same question.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I stepped out of DTE to solve this problem: I created a separate project for the properties and a project for the text templates. This way you compile the assembly with all the data and you can iterate over all the properties using reflection in T4 templates.